# Suppress MsgBox from another Subroutine in VBA

Tags: vba, msgbox

I have a VBA sub that makes a call to a sub that was written by someone else. occasionally, the other sub opens a MsgBox with an OK button. The other sub takes a long time to run, and I am calling it hundreds of times, so I want to be able to run this overnight. Unfortunately, I can't figure out a way to automatically click OK on the MsgBox.

I have tried

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

but this doesn't suppress message boxes.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: This answer to a similar question may get you there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/682732/493055

Comment: Can't you edit the other sub to remove the msgbox call?

Comment: It's password protected. I guess I could ask around to figure out who wrote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is slightly modifying the code of the original sub. You will need to have the necessary permissions tough...

- Modify the header of the original sub by throwing in an extra optinal parameter at the end setting the default value to `True`. This will result in something like `Sub OriginalSubName(`original set of parameters`, Optional ShowMessages = True)`
- At the point where the msgbox is called, modify the code this way:

  ```
  If showMessages = True Then 'The = True part is important here - see below.
  showMessages is a Variant type
      'The original statement that calls the msgBox
  End If
  ```
- Leave the rest of the code of the original sub unchanged
- Modify the line where you call the original sub by throwing in `False` as an extra parameter. This results in `OriginalSubName`your set of parameters`, False`. This way you don't suppress the dialog box by default, but you do when you use it in your sub.

Wonder why I use an optional Variant type parameter?

- The optional part: this prevents other existing subs from crashing when they call the modified sub
- The Variant type part: optional parameters are always Variant type. That's also why you need to use `If showMessages = True Then` instead of just `If showMessages Then`.

Comment: @ Bart: Optional parameters do not always have to be Variant types. The reason they are usually Variants is because you can then use the ISMISSING() function to test if the calling procedure has passed a value for the optional parameter. If the optional parameter is of a type other than Variant then ISMISSING() cannot be used (it will always return FALSE).